# How to reuse code when defining ClassName.create and ClassName.create?

Tags: ruby

Lets say I am wrapping an ActiveRecord class for some reason and I have defined a `create` class method.

```
class BusCreator
  def self.create(attr)
    bus = Bus.new(attr)
    bus.departure_time = bus.arrival_time - bus.trip_duration
    bus.save
    bus
  end
end
```

What's the best way to also define a `create!` method on `BusCreator`? Obviously, it should execute the same logic as `BusCreator.create` but should call `save!` instead of `save`.

Comment: I'm not sure how contrived this example is, but you'd be much better off putting the logic from line 4 into a callback on the AR model itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer depends to some extent on what you want `create!` to do. If you want it to do the same thing as `create`, but raise an exception on failure, you could do something like this:

```
class BusCreator
  def self.create(attr)
    bus = build_bus(attr)
    bus.save
    bus
  end

  def self.create!(attr)
    bus = create(attr)
    if bus.new_record? # check if save succeeded
      raise MyException, 'creation failed!'
    end
    bus
  end
end

class MyException < StandardError; end
```

Otherwise this is simply a matter of extracting the common elements of the methods into a different method which acts as a helper:

```
class BusCreator
  def self.create(attr)
    bus = build_bus(attr)
    bus.save
    bus
  end

  def self.create!(attr)
    bus = build_bus(attr)
    bus.save!
    bus
  end

  private  

  def self.build_bus(attr)
    bus = Bus.new(attr)
    bus.departure_time = bus.arrival_time - bus.trip_duration
  end
end
```

There are lots of style options here, if you really wanted to minimize duplication you could do something like this:

```
class BusCreator
  def self.create(attr)
    bus = build_bus(attr)
  end

  def self.create!(attr)
    bus = build_bus(attr, true)
  end

private  

  def self.build_bus(attr, big_save=false)
    bus = Bus.new(attr)
    bus.departure_time = bus.arrival_time - bus.trip_duration
    big_save ? bus.save! : bus.save
    bus
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had more initialization logic than the one line above and for some reason you couldn't just put that in the AR model itself, you might consider the following:

```
class BusCreator
  def self.create(attr)
    bus = initialize(attr)
    bus.save
    bus
  end

  def self.create!(attr)
    bus = initialize(attr)
    bus.save!
    bus
  end

private

  def self.initialize(attr)
    bus = Bus.new(attr)
    bus.departure_time = bus.arrival_time - bus.trip_duration
    # ...more logic here
    bus
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
class BusCreator
  def self.create(attr)
    real_create(attr, :save)
  end
  def self.create!(attr)
    real_create(attr, :save!)
  end

  #...

  private

  def self.real_create(attr, save_using)
    bus = Bus.new(attr)
    bus.departure_time = bus.arrival_time - bus.trip_duration
    bus.send(save_using)
    bus
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems like a textbook case of over-use of Metaprogramming to me. `#send` offers no real benefit here and introduces "magic" that is only going to make it harder for someone else to pick up this code.

Comment: All I'm saying is that you're introducing complexity at no real benefit. If you have to pass `:save` and `:save!` to your method, why not just call `#save` and `#save!` from `.create` and `.create!` respectively, avoiding any guesswork to a future developer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the example you have given. Specifically this line:

```
bus.departure_time = bus.arrival_time - bus.trip_duration
```

Since `departure_time` depends on `arrival_time` and `trip_duration`, which in turn are both attributes of the same object, there is no reason why this code should be outside `Bus`. Which means, you just wrap it inside a method and then call the method.

If we consider this as a contrived example, and in reality you want to do things more complex than that, then what you really need is a new factory for your `Bus` class other than `new`. So you wrap it in a factory method like this:

```
class Bus

  # ...

  def my_complex_method
    self.departure_time = arrival_time - trip_duration
    # some other complex stuff
    # ...
  end

  # ... 

  # We are doing it here because BusCreator does not and should not 
  # know stuff internal to Bus
  def self.new_with_departure_time(attr, other_optional_stuff)
    bus = new(attr)
    bus.my_complex_method
    bus.process(other_optional_stuff)
    bus
  end
end
```

It is important to note that your abstraction here is not related with `save` and `save!` but with `Bus#new` and `Bus#new` followed by `my_complex_method`. This is because `save` and `save!` represent different behavior and hence have different specs associated with them. So the code that uses these 2 should not actually be abstracted.

Now, coming back to the factory we defined earlier, you would use it like this:

```
class BusCreator

  def self.create(attr)
    bus = Bus.new_with_departure_time(attr, other_stuff)
    bus.save
    bus
  end

  def self.create!(attr)
    bus = Bus.new_with_departure_time(attr, other_stuff)
    bus.save!
    bus
  end

end
```